# Wrong error bug that says to insert ";" and "}" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id: 20190314-1200 -- the latest version of Eclipse EE.

I am getting an error in the IDE on a line of code, that says:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
>        ReturnStatement
>
> Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

I have checked all the { and } and ;. They are all in place.

If I insert a ";" or a "}" like the error instructs, additional errors appear saying the same things.

Is there a bug in Eclipse that anyone knows about?

Here is the code where the error occurs. I marked the exact line the error occurs with a comment that says "error here".

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException, BadJOSEException, JOSEException {
    String idToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (null == idToken) {
        //          throw new CognitoException(NO_TOKEN_FOUND,
        //                  CognitoException.NO_TOKEN_PROVIDED_EXCEPTION, 
        //                  "No token found in Http Authorization Header");
        System.out.println("No token found in Http Authorization Header");
    } else {
        idToken = extractAndDecodeJwt(idToken);
        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = null;
        claimsSet = configurableJWTProcessor.process(idToken, null);
        if (!isIssuedCorrectly(claimsSet)) {
            //                  throw new CognitoException(INVALID_TOKEN,
            //                          CognitoException.INVALID_TOKEN_EXCEPTION_CODE, 
            //                          String.format("Issuer %s in JWT token doesn't match cognito idp %s", 
            //                                  claimsSet.getIssuer(),jwtConfiguration.getCognitoIdentityPoolUrl()));
            System.out.println("Issuer in JWT token doesn't match cognito idp");
        }

        if(!isIdToken(claimsSet)) {
            //                  throw new CognitoException(INVALID_TOKEN,
            //                          CognitoException.NOT_A_TOKEN_EXCEPTION, 
            //                          "JWT Token doesn't seem to be an ID Token");
            System.out.println("JWT Token doesn't seem to be an ID Token");
        }

        String username = claimsSet.getClaims()
                .get("cognito:username").toString();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<String> groups = (List<String>) claimsSet.getClaims()
        .get("cognito:groups");
        List<String> grantedAuthorities = convertList(groups, group-> new 
                SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + group.toUpperCase()));
        User user = new User(username, "", grantedAuthorities);

        return new CognitoJwtAuthentication(user, claimsSet, grantedAuthorities); // error here

              }
}
```

I noticed that the return statement is within another scope (the scope of the if statement) within the method's scope. It looks like the return statement should be outside that inner scope. I wonder if this has something to do with the error?

Comment: Probably. Why not try starting with that?

Comment: @nitind Yes. I changed up the code by removing the if statement the return statement is in, and the errors disappeared. It's something Eclipse needs to fix. There should be an error message that says the return statement is in the wrong scope.

Comment: Compilers often struggle to give good error messages when they are given incorrect code. This is due to the way compiler work and is extremely difficult to do anything about.

Answer (score 0):

In your first if condition you don't return anything from what I see, this would cause a problem as you would end not returning anything where you should here return an "Authentication".

And your before last "}" is not intended correctly you should correct it to make it clearer!

Comment: Yes. It's indented like that because I did a Command+I and had Eclipse auto-indent. I don't know why Eclipse indented it like that.

Comment: Alright, did you try to return something in the first if statement?

Comment: No. I removed the if statement that the return statement is in, so that the return statement is right within the scope of the method.